# How to prevent label overlap in tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, labels

The Latex code below is generated by a C# program of mine.
There are three arrows with a label each. The second label overlaps the first one. To resolve this, the label could be positioned below the arrow (like the third arrow/label), or the arrow/label could be omitted all together.

How can I detect overlap?

Or how to position the label relative to the x-axis, instead of relative to its arrow, as it is now (above/below/omit switch)?

Or how are label position and distance-to-arrow (above=4?) related to the x-axis?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,dutch]{article}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,mode=text,per-mode=symbol,exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,math,quotes,angles}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\tikzstyle{vector}=[->,very thick,xcol]
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, transform shape]
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}
\begin{axis}[
width=6cm,
height=6cm,
xmin={-0.7},xmax={5*1.1},
ymin={-0.1*1.1},ymax={2.335*1.1},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.04,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
grid=both,
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!20},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
axis lines=middle,
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.04,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
xlabel near ticks,
minor tick num=5,
enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
axis x line = bottom,
axis y line = left,
axis line style={-stealth}
] 
\def\closeby{3.2}
\def\spaced{3.7}
\coordinate(Sag1) at (axis cs: 3.5,0);
\coordinate(Sag2) at (axis cs: 3.5,1.835);
\draw[stealth-stealth] [black](Sag1) -- (Sag2)  node [above,midway, rotate=90]{$\qty{2.33}{\meter}$};
\coordinate(Sag1) at (axis cs: \closeby, 0);
\coordinate(Sag2) at (axis cs: \closeby, 2.335);
\draw[stealth-stealth] [red](Sag1) -- (Sag2)  node [above,midway, rotate=90]{$\qty{2.353}{\meter}$};
\coordinate(Sag1) at (axis cs: \spaced, 0);
\coordinate(Sag2) at (axis cs: \spaced, 2.235);
\draw[stealth-stealth] [red](Sag1) -- (Sag2)  node [below,midway, rotate=90]{$\qty{2.353}{\meter}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added an image of your MWE, that makes it easier to understand what you are referring to.

Comment: Maybe you want to shift the label in y-direction. This can be done by replacing `midway` with `pos=0.3` (or similar).

Comment: Οὖτις: not an option, as the black label would still overlap the arrow in the situation shown. Also there may be insufficient space. The position of the arrows along the x-axis is determined by tech calculations in the C# program and therefor cannot be predicted.

Comment: @Erik Couln't the C# program not detect this then? You know roughly how tall the labels are (font size, converted to pt), C# knows how far away the vertical lines, you specify how wide your your PGFPlots diagram is which should allow you to calculate the distance between the vertical lines in pt which you can test against the height of the label.

Comment: With a bit of measuring inside TikZ and drawing the labels from right to left (w/ or w/o the right-most one) we could try to do this inside TikZ as well.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Indeed. Having Latex do the job would be too complicated. Because in my case there are only two arrow/label sets to observe, C# can do the trick much easier: If the red dimension is to the left of the black one, set the red label to 'above' an the black one to 'below'. Otherwise the reverse. If the arrows overlap, in my case one is irrelevant and left out all together. I suppose it is too much to ask from the Latex compiler to find and solve overlap for me...

Comment: @Erik Please consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

- to labels add white background,
- write labels in arrows,
- reduce labels font size
- reduce `inner ysep`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,dutch]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                math,
                quotes,
                angles}
\tikzset{
    >=latex,
vector/.style = {->,very thick},
every picture/.style = {line width=0.75pt},
lbl/.style = {fill=white, font=\scriptsize, inner ysep=0pt, sloped}
        }
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,
            mode=text,
            exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, transform shape]
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}
\begin{axis}[
width=6cm,
height=6cm,
xmin={-0.7},xmax={5*1.1},
ymin={-0.1*1.1},ymax={2.335*1.1},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.04,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
grid=both,
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!20},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
axis lines=middle,
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.04,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
xlabel near ticks,
minor tick num=5,
enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
axis x line = bottom,
axis y line = left,
axis line style={-stealth}
]
\def\closeby{3.2}
\def\spaced{3.7}
\coordinate(Sag1) at (axis cs: 3.5,0);
\coordinate(Sag2) at (axis cs: 3.5,1.835);
\draw[stealth-stealth]      (Sag1) -- node [pos=0.3, lbl] {\qty{2.33}{\meter}}    (Sag2);

\coordinate(Sag1) at (axis cs: \closeby, 0);
\coordinate(Sag2) at (axis cs: \closeby, 2.335);
\draw[stealth-stealth,red]  (Sag1) -- node [pos=0.7, lbl] {\qty{2.353}{\meter}}   (Sag2);

\coordinate(Sag1) at (axis cs: \spaced, 0);
\coordinate(Sag2) at (axis cs: \spaced, 2.235);
\draw[stealth-stealth,red]  (Sag1) -- node [pos=0.7, lbl] {\qty{2.353}{\meter}}   (Sag2);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is increase distance between arrows.

Comment: Labels could still overlap.

Comment: Of course. If distance between arrow ar for example less than 1 pt, or font size is `\huge`.  Sorry, it  is unclear, what you expect and is you like to get.